# ggplot() for multiple datasets on a linear regression

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the dataset:

```
heartData <- structure(list(id = 1:6, biking = c(30.80124571, 65.12921517, 
1.959664531, 44.80019562, 69.42845368, 54.40362555), smoking = c(10.89660802, 
2.219563176, 17.58833051, 2.802558875, 15.9745046, 29.33317552
), heart.disease = c(11.76942278, 2.854081478, 17.17780348, 6.816646909, 
4.062223522, 9.550045997)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here I have used multiple linear regression as model.

```
model.1 <- lm( heart.disease ~ biking + smoking, data = heartData)
```

plotting.data is a synthesized data I am interested in to check the confidence interval around as well as prediction interval.

```
plotting.data <- expand.grid(
  biking = seq(min(heartData$biking), max(heartData$biking), length.out = 5),
  smoking = c(mean(heartData$smoking)))

plotting.data$predicted.y <- predict(model.1, newdata = plotting.data, interval = 'confidence')
plotting.data$smoking <- round(plotting.data$smoking, digits = 2)
plotting.data$smoking <- as.factor(plotting.data$smoking)
```

After running the block of code above, I can see I have created plotting.data with 5 columns however, when I'm running

```
colnames(plotting.data)
```

I get 3 column names. `plotting.data$predicted.y` is only one column and I can't have access or rename `plotting.data$predicted.y[,"fit"], plotting.data$predicted.y[,"upr"]` or `plotting.data$predicted.y[,"lwr"]`

To plot results

```
heart.plot <- ggplot(data = heartData, aes(x = biking, y = heart.disease)) + geom_point()
  + geom_line(data = plotting.data, aes(x = biking, y = predicted.y[,"fit"], color = "red"), size = 1.25)
  + geom_ribbon(data = plotting.data, aes(ymin = predicted.y[,"lwr"], ymax = predicted.y[,"upr"]), alpha = 0.1)
heart.plot
```

I get the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'heart.disease' not found
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. From my own trial and errors, I know that the following part of the code is giving the error. however, I don't know how I can write it in a better way.

```
geom_ribbon(data = plotting.data, aes(ymin = predicted.y[,"lwr"], ymax = predicted.y[,"upr"]), alpha = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you name variables in the `aes()` wrapper in `ggplot()`, it is expected that those variables are available to any data set that you happen to call in the additional `geom`s. If you want to use multiple data sets and they don't necessarily have the same variables, you need to have a separate `aes()` wrapper in each of the `geom`s to better control this issue.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = heartData, aes(x = biking, y = heart.disease)) +
  geom_line(data = plotting.data, aes(x = biking, y = predicted.y[,"fit"]), color = "red", size = 1.25) +
  geom_ribbon(data = plotting.data, aes(x = biking, ymin = predicted.y[,"lwr"], ymax = predicted.y[,"upr"]), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]